# When will the 1,048,577th Milestone happen using the current issuance schedule?

Tags: milestones, private-key

The Coordinator can sign 1,048,576 Milestones before it runs out of new keys and has to resort to key reuse.

At that point there would be a serious security vulnerability in the system due to address reuse by the Coordinator.

According to how many have been issued thus far, and according to how many are being issued every day presently, by what date will the key reuse be anticipated to occur?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, the Coordinator is not forced to resort to key reuse. It could also issue 
transactions from a new Coordinator hash (and anybody who did not update their iri would see no new milestones any more)

That being said, a new milestone is issued once per minute, meaning 1440 milestones per day. And during manual snapshots, the milestone number is rounded to the next thousand.

At the moment, the current milestone is 928,020, so there are 120,556 left, which would last for about 83 days (or a few less in case manual snapshots happen), so the IOTA Foundation should add a second Coordinator hash before March 11, 2019.

Comment: before or on March 11, 2019, and only for full nodes, but yes. Clients and light wallets that only use the API will be unaffected (they don't care about the coordinator hash). Practically speaking, an iri node missing some of the previous updates will likely not function in the current network (well) either, and this change can surely be incorporated in one of the (likely) many updates that have to be done in the next months.